# Convert Excel data to JSON then Post to API

Tags: excel, vba, http, post

I have been using below code which converts the number of excel data into json file like `exportedxls.json` and i want to send this data to API

```
Sub converttojson()
    savename = "exportedxls.json"
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1)
    lcolumn = wks.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lrow = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim titles() As String
    ReDim titles(lcolumn)
    For i = 1 To lcolumn
        titles(i) = wks.Cells(1, i)
    Next i
    json = "["
    dq = """"
    For j = 2 To lrow
        For i = 1 To lcolumn
            If i = 1 Then
                json = json & "{"
            End If
            cellvalue = wks.Cells(j, i)
            json = json & dq & titles(i) & dq & ":" & dq & cellvalue & dq
            If i <> lcolumn Then
                json = json & ","
            End If
        Next i
        json = json & "}"
        If j <> lrow Then
            json = json & ","
        End If
    Next j
    json = json & "]"
    myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & savename
    Open myFile For Output As #1
    Print #1, json
    Close #1
    a = MsgBox("Saved as " & savename, vbOKOnly)
End Sub
```

Here is post json code. But i am unable to know that how still below code will send the above json to api.

I want to use the both code as single when the code will run it will convert and post to api in one call. Your help will be much appreciated.

```
'VBA function to send HTTP POST to a server:
    Function httpPost$(url$, msg$)
        With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
            .Open "POST", url, False
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
            .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            '.setRequestHeader "secret-pass-key", "your-key"    <--if needed
            .send msg
            httpPost = .responseText
        End With
    End Function
```

Comment: Usually JSON are sent as a string as an argument to `.send` method, have you tried that? Without the API documentation, it's difficult to help you what's wrong. I don't think it's necessary to save it as a file.

Comment: No i did not tried because i could find any way online which can do this. Nothing is wrong! because really do not know how the data will send to api. I just need the format. Yes it is not necessary to save the file as json

Comment: After `Close #1` use `RetVal = httpPost$("your url here", json)` make sure that you set the correct headers and `Content-type` in your function as requested by your API (you can find that information in the documentation of your API).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: It is recommended to always declare your variable and to its appropriate variable type, use `Option Explicit` at the top of your module to help you.

Below is an example modified from your code, running `ConvertAndSend` will:

1. Get the JSON string as `apiJSON` from `ConvertJSON` function.
2. Pass `apiJSON` to `httpPost` as an argument which in turns return `.responseText` as `apiResponse`.

Please consult the API documentation on the `Content-Type` header and/or other requirements.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ConvertAndSend()
    Dim apiJSON As String
    apiJSON = ConvertJSON
    
    Dim apiResponse As String
    apiResponse = httpPost("put in api endpoint url", apiJSON)
End Sub

Function ConvertJSON() As String
    
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1)
            
    Dim lcolumn As Long
    lcolumn = wks.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    Dim lrow As Long
    lrow = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim titles() As String
    ReDim titles(lcolumn)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To lcolumn
        titles(i) = wks.Cells(1, i)
    Next i
    
    Dim json As String
    json = "["
    
    Dim dq As String
    
    dq = """"
    
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 2 To lrow
        For i = 1 To lcolumn
            If i = 1 Then
                json = json & "{"
            End If
            
            Dim cellvalue As Variant 'or declare as String
            cellvalue = wks.Cells(j, i)
            json = json & dq & titles(i) & dq & ":" & dq & cellvalue & dq
            If i <> lcolumn Then
                json = json & ","
            End If
        Next i
        json = json & "}"
        If j <> lrow Then
            json = json & ","
        End If
    Next j
    ConvertJSON = json & "]"
End Function

Function httpPost(url As String, msg As String) As String
    With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        .Open "POST", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"    'Don't think it's necessary
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"   'Consult API documentation on the required Content-Type
        '.setRequestHeader "secret-pass-key", "your-key"    <--if needed
        .send msg
        httpPost = .responseText
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you but its not posting the json to API. @Raymond Wu

Comment: @Arham `Debug.Print apiJSON` after `apiJSON = ConvertJSON`.  Check the immediate window and see if the json is correct to the API's requirement. If you have a sample JSON of what the API wants then update your question with the sample and the printed out string.

Comment: @Arham Also, what is the `apiResponse`? Sometimes the API will tells you why it fails.

Comment: Yes i added and it converts the json in immediate window and code works fine no error occurs but data not comes into api, posted new question [New](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68634757/convert-excel-data-to-json-then-post-it-to-api)