# Convert Excel data to JSON then Post it to API

Tags: excel, vba, api

I have been using this below code which converts the data into Json format then post/add to API end points.

But its not working, there is no error occurs. But data is not sent to API. your help will be much appreciated.

I really do not know where the mistake is occurs it converts the data well into json but why it does not post to API. and API response comes empty when see.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ConvertAndSend()
    Dim apiJSON As String
    apiJSON = ConvertJSON
    
    Dim apiResponse As String
    apiResponse = httpPost("put in api endpoint url", apiJSON)
End Sub

Function ConvertJSON() As String
    
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1)
            
    Dim lcolumn As Long
    lcolumn = wks.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    Dim lrow As Long
    lrow = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim titles() As String
    ReDim titles(lcolumn)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To lcolumn
        titles(i) = wks.Cells(1, i)
    Next i
    
    Dim json As String
    json = "["
    
    Dim dq As String
    
    dq = """"
    
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 2 To lrow
        For i = 1 To lcolumn
            If i = 1 Then
                json = json & "{"
            End If
            
            Dim cellvalue As Variant 'or declare as String
            cellvalue = wks.Cells(j, i)
            json = json & dq & titles(i) & dq & ":" & dq & cellvalue & dq
            If i <> lcolumn Then
                json = json & ","
            End If
        Next i
        json = json & "}"
        If j <> lrow Then
            json = json & ","
        End If
    Next j
    ConvertJSON = json & "]"
End Function

Function httpPost(url As String, msg As String) As String
    With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        .Open "POST", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"    'Don't think it's necessary
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"   'Consult API documentation on the required Content-Type
        '.setRequestHeader "secret-pass-key", "your-key"    <--if needed
        .send msg
        httpPost = .responseText
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Update your question with the JSON you converted and sample of the JSON that the API wants.

Comment: So you post the code that you got yesterday as an (accepted) answer (without at least give the credits to Raymond Wu) and expect that someone can tell why the API call fails, without knowing anything about the API itself?

Comment: No its not like that i thanks him yesterday in the comments but its not appearing it happen mistakenly but my intentions were not like that. @FunThomas

Comment: Updated the JSON for two rows @Raymond Wu

Comment: @Arham You are missing the JSON sample that the API requires. Actually while you are at it, provide the whole API details for what you are calling (method, api endpoint url, any other requirements)

Comment: @FunThomas I think he did what he needed to do - the data wasn't posting, which is a differnet question from his original one.

Comment: How to get the JSON sample that api requires @Raymond Wu

Comment: Are you sure this content type `"Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` is correct? I doubt that. You need to read the manual of your API to find out what the correct content type is (we cannot tell you that). And you need to give us the result of `.responseText` as well as `.Status`.

Comment: @Arham the documentation, is the API documentation public? Post it here if so. Without documentation, no one can help you to get it right

Comment: NO i am not sure because i copied it `"Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` how to give the result `.responseText` and `.Status`

Comment: Not its not publically i can send the file personally @Raymond Wu with all the information. including API

Comment: below `httpPost = .responseText` use `Debug.Print .responseText` and `Debug.Print .Status` and check was was written into the immediate window after you run the code.

Comment: here it is `{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"traceId":"|dae5023a-4d8535bd833e851a."} 
 415`  @Pᴇʜ

Comment: Yes what I assumed. Satus code `415` is *"Unsupported Media Type"* means your `Content-type` is wrong. Try to replace `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` with `"application/json"`. check if it is still Status `415`.

Comment: with `"application/json"` the response is `{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|dae5023f-4d8535bd833e851a.","errors":{"$":["The JSON value could not be converted to Sku_scanning_app.Models.Products. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."]}}
 400`

Comment: @Arham well now you have your error message *"The JSON value could not be converted to Sku_scanning_app.Models.Products. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."*. Something is wrong with your json data that you submitted. At least the server accepted the json and gave a valid resonse (error message). But the data in the json is not correct. So that is up to you now to fix that as we cannot help further because we don't know how it should look like. • The JSON is valid but there must be something wrong with the data in it.

Comment: Thank you @Pᴇʜ  for the clarification i will try to sort it out.

Comment: @Arham I had a look at your JSON string and assuming you did paste it correctly, your 2nd row's data has a `vbNewline` in the middle of `CONDITION` 's value which is very weird (and wrong).  Try again but with only with the 1st row data converted to JSON this time and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you for having looked at it again, but same error is appearing `{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|28b3f526-40086b8209871491.","errors":{"$":["The JSON value could not be converted to Sku_scanning_app.Models.UPCs. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."]}}`

Comment: I guess your JSON string is really not in the format that the API wants. We can't help you further until you provide a sample JSON string (usually the manual will have one, check it and compare with yours) @Arham

Comment: I have updated both the json string and the format @Raymond Wu

Comment: @Arham Please refer to my answer below, copy and paste the entire thing to a module. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the JSON sample, it seems that the API only accept 1 row of data at a time so you will have to build a JSON string and send to the API one row at a time.

1. Since the sample JSON does not have a `[]` bracket at the start and end so you need to remove it.
2. `sku`, `uniqueID` and `epid` values are using a numeric value which are not enclosed with `" "` so you will need to remove them as well.

I have modify your code (or mine?) to produce the required format. Running `ConvertAndSend` will now build a JSON string for a row then send it to the API in a loop.

```
Option Explicit

Private wks As Worksheet
Private lcolumn As Long
Private titles() As String

Private Sub ConvertAndSend()
    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    lcolumn = wks.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    GetKeys
    
    Dim lrow As Long
    lrow = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim apiJSON As String
    Dim apiResponse As String
    For i = 2 To lrow
        apiJSON = ConvertJSON(i)
        apiResponse = httpPost("API Endpoint URL", apiJSON)
        Debug.Print apiResponse
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub GetKeys()
    ReDim titles(lcolumn) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To lcolumn
        titles(i) = wks.Cells(1, i)
    Next i
End Sub

Function ConvertJSON(argRow As Long) As String
    Dim dq As String
    dq = Chr(34)

    Dim json As String
    json = "{"
        
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 1 To lcolumn
    
        Select Case titles(j)
            Case "sku", "uniqueID", "epid"
                json = json & dq & titles(j) & dq & ":" & wks.Cells(argRow, j).Value2
            Case Else
                json = json & dq & titles(j) & dq & ":" & dq & wks.Cells(argRow, j).Value2 & dq
        End Select
        
        If j <> lcolumn Then json = json & ","
    Next j
    
    ConvertJSON = json & "}"
End Function

Function httpPost(url As String, msg As String) As String
    With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        .Open "POST", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
        .send msg
        httpPost = .responseText
    End With
End Function
```

I do apologise if the code looks messy as it's late at my area, if the API response is still the same (validation error) then I believe the value you are giving it to is not acceptable which we have no way to help you with this.

Comment: @Arham Please don't accept the answer until you have tested it and confirmed it has solve your problem.

Comment: This is unbelievable.  Thank you soo much @Raymond Wu It is working and response is here `{"message":"UPC already exists. New SKU is added for UPC."}
{"message":"UPC and SKU already Exist"}`